# ASP.NET MVC4 WebGrid how to display all pages in the WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing a model with 1000 rows to a WebGrid.
I need to display them 40 a page.
So there will be 25 pages. However the WebGrid only shows links for the first five, and reviles 2 more as I select the last link, which is more than a little painful.

How can I have WebGrid display all the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a partial answer to my question.

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Prev",
    nextText: "Next >",
    lastText: "Last >>",
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also be done by handle webgrid pagination manually. By getting total pages using **int count = grid.PageCount** you can show all page number and make them hyperlink using a simple loop
For example

```
@{var grid = new WebGrid(source: [MODEL], defaultSort: "[COLNAME]", rowsPerPage: 15, canPage: true, canSort: true, sortFieldName: "[COLNAME]", sortDirectionFieldName: "ASC");
     int count = grid.PageCount;
     @grid.GetHtml(headerStyle: "HeaderClassCSS", footerStyle: "FooterClassCSS", rowStyle: "RowClassCSS", alternatingRowStyle: "AlternateRowClassCSS", columns: grid.Columns(
     grid.Column(columnName: "ChannelID", header: "ID"),
     grid.Column(columnName: "ChannelName", header: "Channel Name"),
     ), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "TableClassCSS" }, mode: WebGridPagerModes.All)
  }
  </div>
     <div style="text-align:center">
     @for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
     {
     //@Url.Action(,"Channels", new { page = i})
        <a href="@Url.Action("Channels", new { page = i})">@(i + " | " )</a>
      }
  </div>
```

**NOTE:** You can disable or hide the built-in footer by using class assigned to footer which is in my case 'FooterClassCSS'. Like

```
.FooterClassCSS
 {
    display:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use in getHtml **numericLinksCount: 25** , this setting will show 25 Page numbers in footer in sliding number.

```
@grid.GetHtml(
                        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                        numericLinksCount: 10,
                        firstText: "<< First",
                        previousText: "< Prev",
                        nextText: " Next >",
                        lastText: "Last >>",
                        tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                        footerStyle: "table-pager",
                        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                        rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style", columns: grid.Columns(
                            gridColumns.ToArray()
                            ));
```